# Safari extension - how to use the setContextEventUserInfo method

Tags: safari-extension

I am building a Safari extension.

On the manual, at the page about "Adding Contextual Menu Items", at the paragraph "Adding Contextual Menu Items Programmatically", it says:

> You can add menu items to the contextual menu by responding to the
>   extension version of the "contextmenu" event in your global page or an
>   extension bar. If you stored information on the event by calling
>   setContextEventUserInfo() in your injected script, you can use that
>   information to help you decide what menu items to add.

Source:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/AddingContextualMenuItems/AddingContextualMenuItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH4-SW1

Now, I have this code on my injected script (as I am trying to pass the selected text to the background script):

```
function handleContextMenu(event) {
  var htmlClip = getHtmlClip(event);
  setContextEventUserInfo(htmlClip);
}
```

Unfortunately that generates this error:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: setContextEventUserInfo

Unfortunately when I searched setContextEventUserInfo on Google, the only result was the page of the Safari manual!

Can please anybody explain to me how I am supposed to use the setContextEventUserInfo method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
function handleContextMenu(event) {
    var htmlClip = getHtmlClip(event);
    safari.self.tab.setContextEventUserInfo(event, htmlClip);
}
```